# Create error message in browser when NullReferenceException exception occurs in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, error-handling, asp.net-ajax

I would like to  create an error message to display on the browser when a `DbNullException` is thrown.

When the user enters the correct `MemberId`, the correct results appear. However when the user enters an incorrect `MemberId`, a `NullReferenceException` is thrown.

Query:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult LoanSearch(string q)
{
        if (q == null)
        {

            throw new Exception("Enter");
        }
      else

        return PartialView(loans);
```

}

```
public List<Loan> GetLoans(string searchString)
{
    var loan = db.Loans
                 .Where(a => a.ISBN.ToString().Contains(searchString) &&
                             a.Book.OnLoan == 1)
                 .OrderByDescending(a => a.LoanId)
                 .FirstOrDefault();

    return new List<Loan> { loan };
}
```

I originally did the following but this a`DbNullException`occurs:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult LoanSearch(string q, Member loanss)
{
    var loans = GetLoans(q, loanss);
    return PartialView(loans);
}

public List<Loan> GetLoans(string searchString, Member loanss)
{
    loanss.errorM = "enter correct member id";

    var loan = db.Members.Where(a => a.MemberId.ToString()
                                      .Contains(searchString) &&
                                     a.Book.OnLoan == 1)
                         .OrderByDescending(a => a.LoanId)
                         .FirstOrDefault();

    if (loan != null)
    {
        return new List<Member> { loan };
    }
    else
    {
        return new List<Member> { loanss };
    }
}
```

In conclusion I want an error message to appear instead of the `an exception` error being thrown and I am not sure how to implement this. Thanks for your time

Here is my ajax:

```
div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">Please enter the ISBN Number of the book</div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        @using (Ajax.BeginForm("LoanSearch", "BookReturn",
                   new AjaxOptions
                   {
                       InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                       HttpMethod = "GET",
                       OnFailure = "searchFailed",
                       LoadingElementId = "ajax-loader",
                       UpdateTargetId = "searchresult",
                   }))
        {
            <input type="text" name="q" />
            <input type="submit" value="search" />
            <img id="ajax-loader"
                 src="@Url.Content("~/Images/ajax-loader.gif")"

            style = "display:none" />
        }
        <div id="searchresult"></div>

                   </div>
</div>
```

Here is were the error lies:in the partial view- @item.Member.Name:

```
        foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <div class="text-center">
                <br />
                <p>Member Name: @item.Member.Name</p>
                <p>Book Title: @item.Book.Name</p>
                <p>Book Author: @item.Book.Author</p>
                <p>Checkout Date: @item.CheckOutDate</p>
                <p>Return Date: @item.ReturnDate</p>
                <br />
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Well, simplistically, you can wrap the query in a `try...catch`:

```
try
{
    var loan = db.Members ...
}
catch (NullReferenceException)
{
    ModelState.AddModelError("searchString", "Danger Will Robinson!");
}
```

However, the real issue is getting this exception in the first place. The problem with returning an error to the user here, is that the user didn't do anything to cause it and is powerless to do anything to correct it. The issue is that `MemberId` is apparently nullable, so you should check for that before calling `ToString()`:

```
.Where(a => a.MemberId != null && a.MemberId.ToString().Contains(searchString) ...
```

**UPDATE**

The only thing in your view that could cause the exception is: `item.Member.Name`. In situations where the id does not match, `item.Member` is null, and null doesn't have a `Name` property, hence the exception. You can fix this simply by doing a null-check:

```
@(item.Member != null ? item.Member.Name : null)
```

Then, if `item.Member` is null, nothing will be output. Otherwise, the value of the `Name` property will be output. Either way, you'll no longer get an exception.

Comment: When I implement this, in the getLoans action method - not all codes return a value

Comment: In situations where `MemberId` is null, nothing will ever match. Perhaps *that* is your problem: why is the column null in the first place?

Comment: When the user enters a valid Memberid the correct results appear, when an incorrect membered is entered then nullreference appears. Instead of nullreference error appearing I want an error message that the user can read to appear

Comment: The `NullReferenceException` is likely being raised in your view, as a result of accessing some property on `Member` that you assume to have a value, but doesn't actually. This is likely due to the fact that you're returning either a `Member` from the database (when the id matches) which will have all the data a `Member` should or the *posted* `Member` (when the id doesn't match), which is probably missing something because it wasn't posted. This has nothing to do with your query or the database.

Comment: Post the code that's actually generating the exception.

Comment: So when the memberid does not match user input since that memberid does not exist how to I show a message to say enter a valid memberid? thanks for your time

Comment: I edited my question to show you were my error lies-in partial view thanks

Comment: I still get the nullreference exception

Comment: Maybe create member object with values of 0 and pass it as a default when nullreference exception occurs. Would this work? not sure how to implement this. really appreciate your time with this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to catch the nullerfernce exception  and redirect the action to error message view action  or show error on the same page state

```
 [HttpGet]
public ActionResult LoanSearch(string q, Member loanss)
{
try
{
    var loans = GetLoans(q, loanss);
    return PartialView(loans);
}
  catch(NullReferenceException)
{ 
       return PartialView(ErrorPage);
}
}
```

Comment: the LoanSearch action method states not all codes return a value when implementing try and catch? and the variable e is declared but not used

Comment: You should go with the second line ommit the first line just Redirect to another action(If you are using ajax to call then this will also not work) and the second the variable declared but never used is a warning not an error just remove the variable e from the exception

Comment: thanks, I am using ajax, so what would be the alternative to redirect to another action when using ajax

Comment: usually  errors are handled in global asax file(best way)  all you need is to throw the exception  and do your coding in global asax file  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/24395wz3.aspx

Comment: but here  you can do something like this i just edited the answer check it again